# Proving G is commutative.

Tags: group-theory

Suppose that $g^2=e$ for all elements $g$ of a group $G$. Prove that $G$ is commutative.

How would I go about doing this proof?

I understand what it means by $g^2=e$, and a group.

Comment: how is this question a duplicate? Does Abelian and commutative mean the same thing?

Comment: Yes. A group is abelian if the binary operation is commutative.

Comment: Oh that makes sense. I thought about it but my professor was dodgy about telling me that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$g^2 = 1$ for all $g \in G \implies g^{-1} = g$.

let $a,b \in G$. We have $ab = (ab)^{-1} = b^{-1} a^{-1} = ba.$ Thus $G$ is abelian.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** You basically only have one move to make:  You know that for any $g, h \in G$ you have $(gh)^2 = e$.  Trying expanding playing with that equation.

Answer (score 1):

Remember what you want to prove is $\forall g, h \in G, gh=hg$, and what you know is $e=hggh = hghg = e$.